# Cookie set is not getting in next refresh

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-4.2

In my laravel 4.2 application, cookie is set via ajax. but on page refresh it is showing that undefined index token ($_COOKIE['token']).

//Add to cart function

```
setcookie('token', $token);
                $token = $this->getcookie('token');
                if(isset($token)){
                     $cart  = Cart::create([ 'user'   => $token ]); 
                } 



public function getcookie($name) { 
        $cookies = [];
        $headers = headers_list();
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            if (strpos($header, 'Set-Cookie: ') === 0) {
                $value = str_replace('&', urlencode('&'), substr($header, 12));
                parse_str(current(explode(';', $value, 1)), $pair);
                $cookies = array_merge_recursive($cookies, $pair);
            }
        }
        return $cookies[$name];
    }
```

And cookie is being set .
But on page refresh, I'm not getting the set cookie value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to give expier time.

```
setcookie('token', $token, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

It will keep the cookie for 30 days.
Check  [This](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

Comment: But i want to remove this cookie as soon as the product is being placed. It may take time or sometimes not. So if I'm setting for 30 days, will I be able to unset it before that expiry?

Comment: to unset it just reset the cookie with same key and past expire time so it will be destroy automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 4.2, attaching cookie in response can be made this way.

### create cookie

```
$cookie  = Cookie::make('unique_token', $token, time() + (86400 * 30));
return Response::make('cookie')->withCookie($cookie);
```

### forget cookie

```
$cookie  = Cookie::forget('unique_token');
return Response::make('cookie')->withCookie($cookie);
```